# Protecting my server from its own users

Tags: permissions, vulnerability

Are there any tools to check my server's file system for permission vulnerabilities?

My server is a low-security web and email server running our local email and website.
Anyone in my organization can use the server, but currently I'm the only user.

I plan on giving user-level access to people and I want to be sure that if they go playing around (perfectly ok), they can't break anything important, like `conf` files and such. In my case if a `conf` file is deleted I'll just recreate it, no money loss or anything, but I'd rather not have to spend the time doing that.

Comment: This is very very broad: anything from "fan speed" to "hard drive diagnostics" to "disk filling up" to "log file X growing rapidly" to "am I fully patched" to "are there users logged in" would fall under "checking if the server is falling apart (or compromised)". As a meta-solution, many people find tools like nagios useful for monitoring.

Comment: I changed the question to be more specific. I've never seen a hold before, how do I request a review? Also I'll check out nagios, so far it looks like a perfect answer.

Comment: I've cast a vote to reopen (needs four other people to agree with me and then you can get answers again).

Comment: Tripwire, samhain, OSSEC, AIDE are common solutions for detecting unexpected file modification

Comment: His question was more from a permissions/vulnerability standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation would be to have the system update automatically.

Assuming a Debian system, if not you can find the equivalent commands.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Put them in a daily `cron` job, to update regularly. However also do it manually once in a while as sometimes those updates need a manual input. Newer versions of apt-get support an `unattended` switch for updates as well, but I still like to run it myself once in a while. Gives me peace of mind.

Then I recommend that you look for the EOL (End of life) of the linux distribution you deployed.

Assuming a Debian system, you can find them all on that page. https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases

For example at the time of this post:

```
Version Code name   Release date        End of life date
8.0     Jessie      April 25th 2015     ~June 6th 2018 (full) / ~June 6th 2020 (LTS)
```

That gives you a deadline of `June 6th 2018` if you installed `Jessie` where you should be going back and upgrading the apt sources to jump to the next version.

Keep in mind that with `LTS` (`long term support`) your distribution will still be getting security updates for a period after the end of life, however it's not forever.

Don't let your server be part of the next https://shodan.io worldwide vulnerability report.

Some other steps that would be relevant for your needs:

- Setup your other users as regular users with ID > 1000
- Setup a cron job to report to you all world-writable files by email
- Disable root password logins from SSH to avoid someone brute forcing it from the inside

Answer (score 0):

You could use some host-oriented IDS tool that check for system file integrity. Ossec is a good example. It sends mail alerts when detect some system file is modified.